# ta.supertrend is not recognised as a function, importing trading view is not possible

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v4

import TradingView/ta/5

```
 s21 = supertrend(21,1)
 s14 = supertrend(14,2)
 s7  = supertrend(17,3)
 long = color(s21)=color(s14)=color(s7)=color.green
 short = color(s21)=color(s14)=color(s7)=color.red
 start = timestamp(IST,2020,1,1,0,0,0)
 end = timestamp(IST,2023,6,250,0,0,0)
 strategy.entry("Buy",strategy.long,100,when = long)
 strategy.close("buy",when = short)
```

I want to buy when the specified supertrends are in an up trend(green) and sell when they are in a down trend(red). I am trying to convert it to version 5 but sends an error
please help...

I tried correcting it in chatgpt,bard and all others did not work ta.supertrend is not recognized

Answer (score 0):

Functions and variables have namespaces in `v5`. See [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_5.html#renamed-functions-and-variables).

You should be using `ta.supertrend`.

Also, below two lines will not compile.

```
long = color(s21)=color(s14)=color(s7)=color.green
short = color(s21)=color(s14)=color(s7)=color.red
```